# Getting null object after passing it via Intent. My object class implements Parcelable interface.

Tags: java, android, android-intent, nullpointerexception, parcelable

Activity 1, from where I send my Parcelable object:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(JobFieldAttribute.this, JobCamera.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();                     
mBundle.putParcelable("FieldData", fieldData); 
mBundle.putSerializable("JobTransaction",jobTransaction);
mBundle.putString("imgPos", 0+"");
intent.putExtra("parce",mBundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

My object class:

```
public class FieldData implements Parcelable {
private Integer id;
private String value;
private Integer job_transaction_id;
private Integer field_attribute_master_id;
private Boolean required;
private View view;
private String viewType;
private String viewLabel;
private String viewSubLabel;
private String viewHelpText;

//All Getter setter methods

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeInt(0);
    dest.writeString(value);
    try{
        dest.writeInt(job_transaction_id);
    }
    catch(Exception e){dest.writeInt(0);}
    dest.writeInt(field_attribute_master_id);
    try{
        dest.writeByte((byte) (required ? 1 : 0));
    }
    catch(Exception e){dest.writeByte((byte)0);}
    try{
        dest.writeString(viewType);
        }
    catch(Exception e){dest.writeString("NOVIEWTYPE");}
    try{
        dest.writeString(viewLabel);
        }
    catch(Exception e){dest.writeString("NO LABEL");}
    try{
        dest.writeString(viewSubLabel);
        }
    catch(Exception e){dest.writeString("NO SUB LABEL");}
    try{
        dest.writeString(viewHelpText);
        }
    catch(Exception e){dest.writeString("NO HELP TEXT");}
}   

public static final Parcelable.Creator<FieldData> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<FieldData>()  {
    @Override
    public FieldData createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        FieldData fieldData = new FieldData();
        fieldData.id = in.readInt();
        Log.i("Pracel in", ">> " + in.readString());
        fieldData.value = in.readString();
        fieldData.job_transaction_id = in.readInt();
        fieldData.field_attribute_master_id = in.readInt();           
        fieldData.required = in.readByte() != 0;
        fieldData.viewType = in.readString();
        fieldData.viewLabel = in.readString();
        fieldData.viewSubLabel = in.readString();
        fieldData.viewHelpText = in.readString();
        return fieldData;
    }

    @Override
    public FieldData[] newArray(int size) {
        return new FieldData[size];
    }
};
```

}

My second activity, which receives this Parcelable object:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_job_camera);
FieldData fieldData = (FieldData) getIntent().getParcelableExtra("fieldData");
```

When i print my fieldData object, i get a NullPointerException. I cannot understand the reason for this error.
What am i doing wrong?
I am a newbie at android development and using Parcelable interface for passing object via Intent.
Please help.

Comment: declare your fielddata appropriatly in the activity from where you sending the intent

Comment: getIntent().getBundleExtra("parce").getParcelableExtra("fieldData");

Comment: @therealprashant fieldData is declared well above the Intent. event after adding this getIntent().getBundleExtra("parce").getParcelableExtra("fieldData");  object is null only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are putting `FieldData` but trying to get back `fieldData`. Combine it with @Dmitry Zaitsev's answer: `getIntent().getBundleExtra("parce").getParcelableExtra("FieldData");`

Answer (score 1):

You're putting `Bundle` to your `Intent` extras, not `FieldData` directly. So, your code should look as follows:

```
getIntent().getBundleExtra("parce").getParcelableExtra("fieldData");
```